# remote desktop: acces to single application

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, remote-access

I have a server running, on which an application is running.
Now I want to gain a person access to this application only.

Is there a good way to give premissions to just one applicaiton without Terminal Services RemoteApp (TS RemoteApp)

hugo

Comment: Any reason for the unaccept? Anything more you need?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need remoteapp in order to publish a single app, it just makes it easier. Look at a reference guide to the RDP file specification, especially the section on alternative shells.

EDIT:

The following syntax should do it.

```
alternate shell:s:c:\Program Files\App\executable.exe
```